# Sticky column does not work - React Table

Tags: reactjs, html-table, sticky, react-table, react-table-v7

I am trying to make the first column in my React Table sticky, however I could not quite get it to work. The first column may still disappear when I scroll horizontally.

What I am doing is in `columns`

```
{
                Header: "First Name",
                accessor: "firstName",
                headerClassname: 'sticky_col'
}
```

CSS

```
.sticky_col {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left:0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library [react-table-sticky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-sticky) to define the sticky column for react-table v7

codeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cori-gl81g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to take zIndex in your CSS

```
.sticky_col {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 9999,
    left:0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

I prefer use this

```
.sticky_col_head {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 9999,
        left:0;
        background-color: white;
    }

.sticky_col_body {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 9998,
        left:0;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

i will use head for cell in table head (Sticky Header) and body for cell in table body (Sticky Column). It will make you sticky header will not hide by your sticky column when you scroll up. (If you use sticky header also). you can try, tell me if you find something.